# How to retrieve records using SQL Server CE and display using Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, sql-server-ce

My report is empty. I have inserted database name `Process_Table` into my Crystal Report and added fields "Quality Code and Quality Name"

But when I open my report, there is no data in it.

What went wrong?

```
public void showReport()
{
        try
        {

            CrystalReport2 objRpt = new CrystalReport2();
            string query = "SELECT * from [Process Table]";  //Your sql query
            SqlCeConnection conn =
                new SqlCeConnection(
                   @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ProcessDatabase.sdf;Persist Security Info=False"); //Your connection


            SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(query, conn);
            ProcessDatabaseDataSet Ds = new ProcessDatabaseDataSet(); 

            adapter.Fill(Ds, "[Process Table]"); // I have space between Process Table
            objRpt.SetDataSource(Ds);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
        }
        catch (SqlException err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete old datagridview, dataset along with all table adapters.
Select Table Right click "New Query"
type your new table without spaces as mentioned below and change your old table name

type EXEC SP_Rename 'Old Table', 'NewTable'.
once done, regenerate your dataset. 
regenerate your datagridview, crystal report will now work fine.

if you have a space between your table, your crystal report may not work.